# Trying to load maven project in tomcat 9, showing A child container failed during start

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I am trying to load maven project in tomcat 9, showing A child container failed during start

[image: showing this error in console]

```
A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@553a3d88]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@553a3d88]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4805)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4940)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:141)
    ... 34 more
```

this is my pom.xml i included database jdbc and mysql dependencies and hibernate spring details

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.rak</groupId>
  <artifactId>mavenspring</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>mavenspring Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>5.1.9.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
        <springsecurity.version>5.2.2.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <!-- <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version> -->
        <hibernate.version>5.4.10.Final</hibernate.version>
        <servlet.version>3.1.0</servlet.version>
    </properties>
  <dependencies>
<!--   Spring -->
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
        <!-- Spring ORM support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.19</version>
</dependency>
 <!-- Spring Security -->
        <!-- spring-security-web and spring-security-config -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-taglibs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>

                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
             <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jdbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.30</version>
</dependency>
<!--        servlet -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>${servlet.version}</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<!--     JSTL TAG -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>mavenspring</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

and also am using spring for configuring

this is my maven spring config xml this am included db details, and db connection is working properly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="com"/>


        <mvc:annotation-driven/>




        <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kp-apps?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC" />
            <property name="user" value="hbstudent" />
            <property name="password" value="hbstudent" /> 

            <!-- these are connection pool properties for C3P0 -->
            <property name="initialPoolSize" value="5"/>
            <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
            <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
            <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" />
        </bean> 


         <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource"     ref="myDataSource"/>
            <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.rak.entities"/>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                     <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
         </bean>


         <bean id="myTransactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
          </bean>


        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />
```

when am adding all related details connecting tomcat it is stopping and getting error

Comment: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@553a3d88]
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)

** this is the error am getting **

Comment: done kindly advice

Comment: This sounds to me like there's something corrupted `ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)`. There's several questions related to that with maven in SO, so check few of them.

Comment: i did not get u

Answer (score 0):

try adding this dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: not working 

am using 

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
   <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
version



<spring-framework.version>5.1.9.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

Answer (score 0):

Man, I'm sure you've already solved this problem. I had the same problem with Tomcat 9.0.36 and Apache Maven 3.6.3. So read this article and make sure you have done all steps in it https://programmer.group/how-to-configure-tomcat-9.0-in-maven.html.

> You also need to be sure that you sat your settigs.xml in the path for Maven in your IDE. If you use Eclipse read this article: https://howtodoinjava.com/maven/maven-proxy-settings/. I hope this will help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your advice.) Next time I will make my answer more useful than that